# Which hook can I use to update programmatically a product in drupal commerce?

Tags: drupal-8, commerce

I need to programmatically update a product with drupal commerce.

Which hook can I use?

And how can I get the value of the variation? If for example I have a field in the product variation which is field_newvar?

(In drupal 7 I used

```
 hook_node_presave($node) {
```

and then got the commerce product entity with entity_metadata_wrapper but now in drupal8  we don't need nodes to show products.)

Comment: try [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/9.0.x)..

Comment: thank you it worked but I can't save the value I tried 
function hook_commerce_product_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

$result = $entity->get('title')->value;

$entity->set('field_essai', $result);
$entity->save();
}